# Seeding data in startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Is it OK to seed data in the startup.cs? Are there any advantages, disadvantages to doing it there rather than in the DbContext or Migration Configuration Class?

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ConfigureAuth(app);
    SeedData();
}
public void SeedData()
{
    using (ApplicationDbContext _db = new ApplicationDbContext())  {
        if (!_db.Books.Any(n => n.Name == "Seeded in Startup.cs"))
        {
            _db.Books.Add(new Book() { Name = "Seeded in Startup.cs", Date = "1966" });
        }
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you need other services (Logging, ...) it might be an idea to create a Scope. I have seen examples (eShopOnContainers) where that is done in Program.Main()

Comment: this code will run every time you start your app. If it is ok to you - why not?

Comment: I would place the SaveChanges inside the `if()` though.

Comment: And on a second read, you certainly don't want this spelled out inside your startup code, create a separate MyContextSeed class near the actual Context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We created a **SeedHelpers.cs**
In this file all seed data are available.

```
public async Task Seed()
        {
            try
            {
                if (RoleManager.Roles.ToList().Count == 0)
                    foreach (string role in typeof(RoleConst).GetConstValue<string>())
                        await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new RoleEntity { Name = role.ToString() });

                if (UserManager.Users.ToList().Count == 0)
                {
                    UserEntity entity = new UserEntity
                    {
                        Email = "y",
                        Active = true,
                        Deleted = false,
                        EmailConfirmed = true,
                        Created = DateTime.UtcNow,
                        Modified = DateTime.UtcNow,
                        Name = "y",
                        UserName = "x"
                    };
                    await UserManager.CreateAsync(entity, "fg@123");
                    await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(entity, RoleConst.Admin);
                    //Send Invitation email to Admin in the Production.
                }
                if(DapperLanguage.All().ToList().Count()==0)
                {
                    await DapperLanguage.AddAsync(new Language
                    {
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        Code = LanguageConst.English,
                        Name = "English"
                    });
                    await DapperLanguage.AddAsync(new Language
                    {
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        Code = LanguageConst.Arabic,
                        Name = "Arabic"
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogManager.LogError(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { class_name = this.GetType().Name, exception = ex }));
            }
        }
```

And In **Startup.cs** file

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app, Helpers.SeedHelpers seed)
{
    ConfigureAuth(app);
    seed.Seed().Wait();
}
```

Try this type of method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ef core you can now use HasData() in the ef mapping configurations:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding

If using ef 6 you can set an initialiser on the DbContext and maybe store the seed data for each entity in a separate file in a separate project?

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/seed-database-in-code-first.aspx